# .htaccess Rewrite Filename as Page

Tags: .htaccess, pdf, url-rewriting

I'm trying to have my .htaccess file rewrite a URL with this ending:

/Management_Agreement_fillable.pdf

as:

/?page=viewer&viewer=G&fileID=1

However, when I try the following:

```
RewriteCond ^/Management_Agreement_fillable.pdf$
RewriteRule (.*) /?page=viewer&viewer=G&fileID=1 [R=301,L]
```

It doesn't work. What should I be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the condition:

```
RewriteRule ^Management_Agreement_fillable\.pdf$ /?page=viewer&viewer=G&fileID=1 [R=301,L]
```

If you don't want the URL in the address bar to change, remove the `R=301,` from the square brackets.

Comment: This also works great, and is the simpler of two solutions. Thank you!